# Changing a variable causes changing an object

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I created a `HashMap` class with some methods. Then I'm creating an object of this class (`objectA`) and putting an array into it. And then I'm extracting this array to do some changes with it and putting changed array into new `objectB`. But with changing extracted array, my `objectA` has changed too! Why this happening?

Here is full working example:

```
public class MyClass extends LinkedHashMap<String, int[]> {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyClass objectA = new MyClass();
    objectA.put("somekey", new int[]{1,2,3});
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(objectA.get("somekey"))); // [1,2,3]
    MyClass objectC = objectA.myMethod(); // I did nothing with my objectA
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(objectA.get("somekey"))); //[0,10,20]    but objectA has changed! 

}

public int[] getValues(String key){
    int[] result = this.get(key);
    return result;
}

public void putValues(String key, int[] values){
    this.put(key, values);
}

public MyClass myMethod(){
    MyClass objectB = new MyClass();
    //getting array from hashmap
    int[] values = this.getValues("somekey");
    //now I'm changing the array
    for (int i=0; i<values.length; i++){
        values[i] = i*10;
    }
   // and my objectA(this) has been changed!
   objectB.put("anotherkey", values);

    return objectB;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior is because in Java every object holds the reference, not the value. 
So, in your case

```
objectA.put("somekey", new int[]{1,2,3});
```

a reference is stored of the `int array`.

Then, when you calling the `objectA.myMethod()`, in `myMethod()` you are getting the same reference of the array.
Then you have modified the same array and putted back with `anotherkey` key which is still having the same reference.

Therefore, your `objectA.get("somekey")` has changed.

For more info check this question: [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/725306)

Comment: Thank you for explanation! It's not easy to understand this philosophy of java.

Comment: you can understand this much better after looking for *What is pass-by-value and pass-by-reference?* and *How Java deals with this?*

Comment: I'll read about this. But for now I don't understand why java working with references not values.

Comment: Java objects always hold the reference of the memory where the object's instance is stored.

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop is directly modifying the array of integers stored in `objectA`. You can get the desired behavior by making a copy of the array:

```
public MyClass myMethod(){
    MyClass objectB = new MyClass();

    int[] values = this.getValues("somekey");
    int[] temp = Arrays.copyOf(values, values.length);

    for (int i=0; i<values.length; i++){
        temp[i] = i*10;
    }

    objectB.put("anotherkey", temp);

    return objectB;
}
```